# Date Input Shows on VF Page but not Site

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites, permissions, site.com

I have created a request form for our clients, and to provide access to the form I have developed a site URL for them to access the form.

There is a field called request date in the form it is showing up in the normal preview page in the  SF platform.

[image]

but in the Site URL the request date field is showing only the label nat the input box.

[image]

Please advise

```
<apex:actionRegion renderRegionOnly="false">
    <table style="width:100%;">
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align:right;width:35%;font-weight:bold;font-size:11px;color: #4a4a56;padding-right: 2px;">
                <apex:outputLabel value="Request Date" for="RequestDate"/>
            </td>
            <td style="padding-left: 10px;">
                <apex:inputField value="{!prf.Request_Date__c}" styleClass="form-control" required="true" label="Request Date" id="reqdate"/>
            </td>      
        </tr>
    </table>
</apex:actionRegion>
```

Comment: Did you give the Site Guest User edit access on that field?

Comment: @adrianlarson Yes I did

Comment: @adrian please find the mark up i have included.

Comment: @SamuelRobert also give edit access as well of this field.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar problem many a times and issue is mostly caused by Field Level Security. To Check you have given appropriate FLS follow below steps:

1. Go to Setup->Develop->Sites->Click on label of Site to which this page belongs.
2. Clcik on button named 'Public Access Setting' .It will open profile of site guest user.
3. Navigate to Field level security section and click on object to which this field belongs.
4. Make sure Read Access and Edit Access is given appropriately. You must have edit access for your case.
5. Save FLS and revisit site page to check if it works.

Comment: I had given read access to that field still it did not show up the date field.

Comment: You need edit access and not read.

Comment: I have checked both boxes read as well as edit.

Answer (score -1):

If you have permission sets assigned to the **Site Guest User**, then make sure that you have given the **edit** permission for the date field (**Request Date**).

Comment: I already clarified this point in the comments...